# Is it possible to keep DataSet automatically synced with a SQLite database?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, ado.net

I'm trying to learn to use SQLite, but I'm very frustrated and confused. I've gotten as far as finding System.Data.SQLite, which is apparently the thing to use for SQLite in C#.

The website has no documentation whatsoever. The "original website", which is apparently obsolete from 2010 onwards, has no documentation either. I could find a few blog tutorials, but from what I can tell their method of operation is basically:

1. Initialize a database connection.
2. Feed SQL statements into the connection.
3. Take out stuff that comes out of the connection.
4. Close connection.

I don't want to write SQL statements in my C# code, they're ugly and I get no assistance from the IDE because I have to put the SQL code in strings.

Can't I just:

- Create a `DataSet`.
- Tell the `DataSet` that it should correspond to the SQLite database `MyDB.sqlite`.
- Manipulate the `DataSet` using its member functions.
- Not worry about SQLite because the `DataSet` automatically keeps itself in sync with the SQLite database on disc.

I know that I can fill a `DataSet` with the contents of a database, but if I want access to the entire database I will have to fill the `DataSet` with all of its contents. If my database is 1 GB, I have just used up 1 GB of RAM (not to mention the time needed to write all of it at once).

Can't I simply take a SQLite database connection and pretend it's just an ordinary `DataSet` (that perhaps needs to be asked occasionally if it's done syncing yet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question is no.
No you cannot simply take a SQLite connection pretend it's just a DataSet.

If you don't want to code SQL statements then consider Entity Framework.
[Using SQLite Embedded Database with Entity Framework and Linq-to-SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236918/Using-SQLite-embedded-database-with-entity-framewo)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't treat a `DataSet` as a database. It's just a result of a query.

You query the database to get a *subset* of data (you never want ALL the data from your DB) and this subset is used to populate your `DataSet`.

You are required to synchronize your changes manually because `DataSet` doesn't know which updates should be a part of which transaction. This is your system knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The DataSet is an in memory cache and will only synchronize to the underlying data store when the developer allows it. You could put a timer wrapper around in and do it on a schedule but you still need to keep the Dataset and data store synchronized manually.

Storing 1GB+ of data is really not recommended as the memory usage would be very high and the performance very low. You also don't want to be sending that amount of data over a network or god forbid an internet connection.

Why would you want to keep 1GB of data in memory?